# How to prevent magit from formatting tabs and spaces

Tags: emacs, magit

I use [SmartTabs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs) in my code.

I've discovered that [Magit](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Magit) has been undoing some of my indentation in my commits. Namely it doesn't like mixed tabs and spaces in a single line.

Example:

```cpp
function(parameter1,
.........parameter2,
.........[](){
.........\t // Code goes here
.........});
```

Where `.` is a space and `\t` is a tab.

I want the code to be lined up with the function name (spaces) but then indented in the lambda (tabs).  Magit will either move the tabs to the left of the spaces or convert all of the spaces to tabs.

I've tried adjusting every setting I can find and have even commented out all references to git's white-spaces parameters in Magit's source, but it's still doing it.

How do I disable this "feature" of Magit?

Temporarily I've been using `git add --interactive`.

---

Reproduction:

```sh
mkdir test_dir
cd test_dir
git init
touch test_file.c
git add test_file.c
git commit -m "Message 1"
emacs test_file.c
M-:(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") ("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")))
M-:(package-refresh-contents)
M-:(package-install 'magit)
<Space>C-q<Tab>text
M-x magit-status
# arrow down to the file
s
```

Comment: Are you saying that the code which gets staged/committed is *different* to the original/unstaged code?  I'd be really surprised if Magit was causing anything like that.  My initial guess would be that the visual display of diffs is using a different `tab-width` to that used in the code, but that the *committed* code should not have changed.  Can you clarify precisely where/how this issue manifests, and can you provide a recipe for reproducing the problem starting from `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Since `emacs -Q` doesn't ignore my local changes to `magit`, I replicated it under a blank user account. Intriguingly the behavior goes away if the `org` repository isn't included.

Comment: I followed your recipe, and in all situations -- before staging, after staging, after committing -- I see a space followed by a tab for the indentation, just as per the original text.  I am using Magit 20200208.551, Git 2.8.3, Emacs 26.3, gnu/linux.

Comment: Oh, wait, I misunderstood and ignored your `org` repo note.  I need to try again.  That sounds *weird*.

Comment: Well that change made no difference for me (which I'm glad to report, frankly).  I can't replicate the issue with your recipe.

Comment: I couldn't replicate it in a vm.  While trying to find out why, it stopped happening on my box.  Down the rabbit hole of heisenbugs I go.